# CalculateRoute returning different numbers to and from the same two places

Tags: here-api

When using calculate route I am getting different numbers for the same two locations going to and from said locations. I would understand if it were a few miles but I am getting some that are a 20+ mile difference which seems off to me.
My query:

```
https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.xml?app_id={app-id}&app_code={app-code}&mode=fastest;truck&height=5&waypoint0=geo!41.85071,-87.67896;500&waypoint1=geo!40.76282,-81.34159;500
```

This query returns

> 442 miles

and if I switch the points:

```
https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.xml?app_id={app-id}&app_code={app-code}&mode=fastest;truck&height=5&waypoint0=geo!40.76282,-81.34159;500&waypoint1=geo!41.85071,-87.67896;500
```

This query returns

> 392 miles

.

I'm guessing there is something I am missing in my query but I can't seem to figure out what. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can add the parameter  `truckRestrictionPenalty=soft`

> **Note:-The soft penalty requires the route notes to be enabled in the
>   response**.

```
https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?apiKey={api_key}&mode=fastest;truck&waypoint0=geo!41.85071,-87.67896;500&waypoint1=geo!40.76282,-81.34159;500&truckRestrictionPenalty=soft&routeattributes=notes&maneuverattributes=notes
```

> 393 miles

```
https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?mode=fastest;truck&waypoint0=geo!40.76282,-81.34159;500&waypoint1=geo!41.85071,-87.67896;500&truckRestrictionPenalty=soft&routeattributes=notes&maneuverattributes=notes&apiKey={api_key}
```

> 392 miles

https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/example-truck-route-violating-restriction.html

Comment: I see that you removed the &height=5 from the search. Doing that but not adding the truckRestrictionPenalty=soft parameter gives me similar results. However, I need to use that height parameter. Is there a way to make that work?
[My Search](https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.xml?app_id={app_id}&app_code={app_code}&mode=fastest;truck&waypoint0=geo!41.85071,-87.67896;500&waypoint1=geo!40.76282,-81.34159;500&height=5&truckRestrictionPenalty=soft&routeattributes=notes&maneuverattributes=notes)
<- Flipping the points still gives me a 50 mile difference.